# HBase client thread stuck waiting on HBaseClient.call()

Tags: java, hbase

I have a standalone instance of HBase (single instance, on localhost, no Hadoop).

After reading a few thousand records using a scanner my thread gets stuck waiting, always on the same record.

Additionally if I run count 'table' from the hbase shell it also get's stuck, at about record 10k.

```
hbase(main):001:0> count 'cache'
```

There are no errors, or anything unusual in the HBase logs.

In both instances the client thread in the HBase server is stuck waiting:

```
"main" prio=10 tid=0x0000000001102000 nid=0xbd1 in Object.wait() [0x00007f8e9088f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:757)
```

Any clues?

Comment: Are you also adding data in the background? Is HBase doing a compaction by any chance?